# concentric circles in processing

Tags: loops, processing

I have been coding for two months now and I decided to try and do concentric circles as a project in processing. It has been two weeks and I have figured out how to create the circles, but I want to randomize the colour of each circle but not make it look like rainbow road from Mario Kart.Here is my code hope you can help

```java
void setup()
{  
  size(500,500);
  background(131);
}


void draw()
{

  coolCircles();

}


void coolCircles()
{       
  for(int x = 500; x >= 20; x-=20)
  {
      int r = (int)(random(1,255));
      int g = (int)(random(1,255));
      int b = (int)(random(1,255));

      fill(r, g, b);
      ellipse(250, 250, x, x);
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you put `noLoop()` in `setup()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general questions like this. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

I'm assuming that when you say:

> not make it look like rainbow road from Mario Kart

You mean you want to restrict the colors of the circles. There are a million different ways to do that, and which approach you choose depends on exactly what you want to do. I suggest [breaking your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and trying to write out what you want to happen, in English, before you think about implementing it with code.

But the key is going to be this section of your code:

```
int r = (int)(random(1,255));
int g = (int)(random(1,255));
int b = (int)(random(1,255));

fill(r, g, b);
```

This is where you come up with the colors. You need to restrict these numbers. Again, how you do that depends on what you want to happen. But for example:

```
float gray = random(256);
fill(gray);
```

This would give you a grayscale palette instead of a rainbow palette. Or:

```
float r = random(256);
fill(r, 0, 0);
```

This would give you a red palette. Or:

```
float r = random(256);
float g = random(r);
float b = random(r);
fill(r, g, b);
```

This would give you colors that were *mostly* red, but with some green and blue thrown in as well.

The point is that you need to first be able to explain (to yourself, in English) exactly what you're trying to do. When you have that, then you can play with the code to get the effect you're going for. Good luck.